# Searching String In All Tables And Displaying It With Pagination Technique

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

My database has five tables:

```
Computer|Mobile|Tablet|MusicSystem|Camera
```

All the tables are in same structure like:

```
productID|ProductBrand|Price|userId
```

Here, I want to search product's brand name in all the field of `productBrand` in all the tables, where `userId=$userId` and limit is 10 then  display it with pagination technique.

How can I create such a query in MySQLi and display it in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) You have to search in every table and then use `union` to combine them and then finally use limit to select only a page b) You should fix your database design, your 5 tables belong into 1 table. Who set this up? It makes no sense. c) If you would have such a correct database design, you would only need to do one `select * from yournewtable where userId = $userId limit 10`.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

select * from Computer c,Mobile m,Tablet t,MusicSystem ms,Camera cam where userId = $userId and (c.productBrand = searchingProductBrand or  m.productBrand = searchingProductBrand or t.productBrand = searchingProductBrand or ms.productBrand = searchingProductBrand or cam.productBrand = searchingProductBrand )  limit 10

Answer (score 0):

If you are following same structure for each category table,better structure is to categorize all into single table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `category_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Computer'),
(2, 'Mobile'),
(3, 'Tablet'),
(4, 'MusicSystem'),
(5, 'Camera');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `ProductId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductBrand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Price` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CatId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`),
  KEY `CatId` (`CatId`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CatId`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`ProductId`, `ProductBrand`, `Price`, `UserId`, `CatId`) VALUES
(1, 'Lenovo', '35000', 5, 3),
(2, 'Asus', '28350', 5, 2),
(3, 'Dell', '25000', 5, 3),
(4, 'MotoG', '12500', 5, 2),
(5, 'Samsung', '52000', 4, 1);
```

You can get your result using

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE userId = '5'
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/457fe/3/0)